# cannot change amplify cognito email template for event AdminCreateUser

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-ses

I have a lambda script triggered by customMessage of cognito. It should customize my authentication email templates. It works great with all events except `AdminCreateUser`.

So it is a short question, Why it does not works?

```js
const sign_up_message = async(event) => {
    let template = templateGenerator(templates.MAIN, templates.CONFIRM_SIGN_UP);
    let code = event.request.codeParameter;

    event.response = {
        emailSubject: "Jouw verificatiecode voor de app",
        emailMessage: mustache.render(template, {
            title: "Bevestig je account",
            preHeader: "Bevestig je account met de verificatiecode",
            s3Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
            activationCode: code
        })
    }

    return event
}

const admin_create_user_message = async(event) => {
    let template = templateGenerator(templates.MAIN, templates.ADMIN_CREATE_USER);

    let email = event.request.usernameParameter;
    let code = event.request.codeParameter;

    event.response = {
        emailSubject: "Je account bij financiallease.nl is hersteld",
        emailMessage: mustache.render(template, {
            title: "Je account bij financiallease.nl is hersteld",
            preHeader: "Wachtwoord resetten is verplicht",
            s3Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
            username: email,
        })
    }

    return event
}
const resend_code_message = async(event) => {
    let template = templateGenerator(templates.MAIN, templates.RESEND_CODE_MESSAGE);
    let code = event.request.codeParameter;

    event.response = {
        emailSubject: "Jouw verificatiecode voor de app",
        emailMessage: mustache.render(template, {
            title: "Bevestig je account",
            preHeader: "Bevestig je account met de verificatiecode",
            s3Bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET,
            activationCode: code
        })
    }

    return event
}

exports.handler = async(event) => {
    switch (event.triggerSource) {
        case "CustomMessage_SignUp": //Sign-up trigger whenever a new user signs him/herself up.
            return sign_up_message(event)
        case "CustomMessage_AdminCreateUser": //When the user is created with adminCreateUser() API
            return admin_create_user_message(event)
        case "CustomMessage_ResendCode": //When user requests the code again.
            return resend_code_message(event)
        case "CustomMessage_ForgotPassword": //Forgot password request initiated by user
            return forgot_password(event)
        case "CustomMessage_UpdateUserAttribute": //Whenever the user attributes are updated
            return update_user_attribute_message(event)
        case "CustomMessage_VerifyUserAttribute": //Verify mobile number/email
            return verify_user_attribute(event)
        case "CustomMessage_Authentication": //MFA authenitcation code.
            return authenitcation_message(event)
        default:
            return event
    }
};
```

And when i test it locally i get the correct template. Once it is in the cloud. I will get the default cognito template:

[image]

As you can see the subject is changed but the body still the default from AWS. What's wrong with this? Any help pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was because the template expect to have {{ code }} variable witch is required to send temporary password to the users. I just added this variable to my custom template as hidden tag.